# Linq to Sql - Using multiple inner joins with multiple parameters

Tags: c#, linq-to-sql

So far, i've seen a lot of SO questions about multiple inner joins, but none of them solved my issues. I've been trying to do an inner join on 2 tables and a subselect on a third table using one of the previous table.

Here's the sql code:

```
SELECT 
//It's a lot of select fields here. Nothing really useful to solve the problem 
FROM 
    SCHEDULES
INNER JOIN 
    STATUS
ON
    SCHEDULES.COMPANY              = STATUS.COMPANY          AND 
    SCHEDULES.BANK                 = STATUS.BANK             AND 
    SCHEDULES.PRODUCT              = STATUS.PRODUCT          AND 
    SCHEDULES.IDSTRING             = STATUS.IDSTRING         AND 
    SCHEDULES.RECEIVER       = 'ADMILSONDAMASCENO'     AND
    SCHEDULES.SCHEDULING < GETDATE()                   AND
    SCHEDULES.IDSTRING IN (
        SELECT DISTINCT IDSTRING  FROM DEBTS_BBRASIL WHERE
        DEBITOS_BBRASIL.COMPANY        = SCHEDULES.COMPANY        AND
        DEBITOS_BBRASIL.BANK           = SCHEDULES.BANK           AND
        DEBITOS_BBRASIL.PRODUCT        = SCHEDULES.PRODUCT        AND
        DEBITOS_BBRASIL.IDSTRING       = SCHEDULES.IDSTRING       AND
        DEBITOS_BBRASIL.STATUS         <> 2
)
ORDER BY SCHEDULES.SCHEDULING DESC
```

And here's what've tried to do with linq to sql:

```
 from sched in SCHEDULES
    join status in STATUS
      on new { sched.IDSTRING, sched.COMPANY, sched.BANK, sched.PRODUCT } 
      equals new { status.IDSTRING, status.COMPANY, status.BANK, status.PRODUCT } 
    into schedStats
    from ss in schedStats
    join debt in DEBITOS_BBRASILs
      on new { ss.IDSTRING, ss.COMPANY, ss.BANK, ss.PRODUCT }
      equals new { debt.IDSTRING, debt.COMPANY, debT.BANK, debt.PRODUCT }
    where sched.RECEIVER.Equals("ADMILSONDAMASCENO") && 
                         sched.SCHEDULING <= DateTime.Now && debt.STATUS != 2
    select new ScheduledStatus
    {
      //Lots of properties here
    };
```

That code above, however, produces a `Cross-Join` then an `Inner-Join`, which i'm positive is duplicating some results. Testing the first code on SqlServer produces 189 results, while my linq to sql code produces 546 results. I don't know how reproduce the same sql code to linq to sql code.

I've tested it both on linqPad just to be sure.

Comment: Have you tried looking at the generated sql for clues?  DbContext.Log = Console.Out (where DbContext is your dbContext) will put the generated SQL in your output window when debugging.

Comment: Since you already have the TSQL written why not just use a table value function. Then just call the function using LINQ to SQL. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms191165(v=SQL.100).aspx

Comment: Didn't know table value functions, thanks for showing it. However, i can't use it because we have a strict policy not to put any logics on database.

Comment: @JohnieKarr I've already seen the generated query by debugging the code and through linqPad. That's how i know it's producing a Cross-Join with a Inner-Join.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found my answer after a great amount of 'googling'. I was needing a subquery to perform a search on another table, not another join. Using the linq to sql method `Any` did the trick. Here's [the post](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/forums/en-US/linqprojectgeneral/thread/360166df-4e50-44d8-812a-04b5bc4fedd1/) that helped me most.

And here's the linq to sql code that translated my TSQL code:

```
    from sched in SCHEDULES
        join status in STATUS
          on new { sched.IDSTRING, sched.COMPANY, sched.BANK, sched.PRODUCT } 
          equals new { status.IDSTRING, status.COMPANY, status.BANK, status.PRODUCT } 
        where sched.RECEIVER.Equals("ADMILSONDAMASCENO") && 
              sched.SCHEDULING <= DateTime.Now && DEBITOS_BBRASILs.Any(dbb=> 
                    dbb.IDSTRING.Equals(sched.IDSTRING) 
                     && dbb.COMPANY.Equals(sched.COMPANY) 
                     && dbb.BANK.Equals(sched.BANK) 
                     && dbb.PRODUCT.Equals(sched.PRODUCT)
                     && dbb.STATUS != 2)
        select new ScheduledStatus
        {
         //Lots of properties here
         };
```

Answer (score 1):

When using LINQ to SQL explicit joins should normally not be used. If you have set up the correct relations, you should have navigation properties that you can use. With those, the query would be something like:

```
from sched in SCHEDULES
where sched.status.debt != 2;
```

If you have foreign keys in the database, the navigation properties are automatically generated by SqlMetal.exe or by the OR designer when you drop the two tables on the designer surface. The relation between the tables will be shown with a line (see example below).

[image: Sample navigation properties]

Comment: I agree with you. I've seen it on some blogs. It's called association, right? Unfortunately, the database i work on doesn't have that association (through fk) on those tables. And even worse, i can't change it because it's a legacy system that depends on how those tables currently works. Anyway, thanks for your answer.

Comment: You can add the associations manually in the OR designer too, without affecting the DB.